# How to assign a list of strings from an Excel range to an Outlook VBA variable?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do I assign a list of stings from an excel range to an outlook vba variable?

I have the following running in Outlook. I Intend to pull a list of email addresses (strings) from an Excel sheet, for sender comparison.

```vb
Sub OutlookExcel()
    
    'declare variables
    Dim xExcelFile As String
    Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xWs As Excel.Worksheet
        
    'declare xls file
    xExcelFile = "[path]\test1.xlsx"
    'open the xls file
    Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile)
    Set xWs = xWb.Sheets(1)
       
    ' get the email adresses. here i get into trouble
    Dim rng As Variant
    Set rng = xWs.Range("A2:A3")
        
    Debug.Print rng(1)
    Debug.Print rng(2)
    Debug.Print rng(3)
    Debug.Print rng(9)
    Debug.Print rng(10)
    Debug.Print rng(0)            
End Sub
```

which returns

```
A2
A3
A4
A10

A1
```

with my "email addresses" in test1.xlsx as follows:
[image]

Note that I specified rng to be the two cells "A2:A3", yet, cells A1 until A10 are contained. rng(100) returns the empty string.

I would like a list object with indices 1 and 2, containing "A2" and "A3". In a second step, I need my list to contain cell A2 until the last nonempty cell of column A.

**EDIT**
The above is the minimal example. The context is that I want to check incoming email Items for their sender address and move them to according folders.

The key problem is that the list of email addresses I obtain seems to be infinitely long to the for each loop:

```vb
Function Findstring(email As String, rng2 As Variant) As Integer
    'returns -1 if email is not found in rng2, otherwise its index

    Findstring = -1
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For Each Item In rng2  'never stops, i ever increases => function doesnt return
        If email = Item Then
            Findstring = i
            Exit For
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Function
```

where the array rng2 is the list with emails, made below:

```vb
Sub GetEMailsFolders(ByRef rng1 As Variant, ByRef rng2 As Variant, ByRef n As Variant)
    
    'declare variables
    Dim xExcelFile As String
    Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xWs As Excel.Worksheet
        
    'declare email & folder xls file
    xExcelFile = "C:\temp\temp.xlsx"
    'open the file
    Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile)
    Set xWs = xWb.Sheets(1)
        
    'extract folders (column A), emails (column O) and thir number
    n = xWs.Range(xWs.Range("A2"), xWs.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Count  'works
    Set rng1 = xWs.Range(xWs.Range("A2"), xWs.Range("A2").Offset(n - 1, 0)) 'folder names
    Set rng2 = xWs.Range(xWs.Range("O2"), xWs.Range("O2").Offset(n - 1, 0)) 'emails
End Sub
```

At the very end I need a workspace variable containing a (finite) list that I can a) iterate via *for each* and b) index like *list(1)* to *list(N)*

**[solution]**

My "hack" is to ReDim the variant to a known length, and assign each element:

```vb
n = xWs.Range(xWs.Range("A2"), xWs.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Count ' works
ReDim rng1(1 To n) As Variant
For i = 1 To n
    rng1(i) = xWs.Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Debug.Print rng1(i), rng2(i)
Next
```

Everything runs smoothly now.
Still I am flabbergasted by that variant behavior or I haven't understood it.

Answer (score 0):

*Is this what you are trying to do?*

```
Option Explicit
Sub OutlookExcel()
    'declare variables
    Dim xExcelFile As String
    Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xWs As Excel.Worksheet

    'declare xls file
    xExcelFile = "C:\Temp\Temp.xlsm"
    'open the xls file
    Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile)
    Set xWs = xWb.Sheets(1)

    ' get the email adresses. here i get into trouble
    Dim rng As Variant
    Set rng = xWs.Range("A2:A3")

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In rng
        Debug.Print Cell.Value
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: no, unfortuanately not. see the edit of the OP for more clarification